# Strange characters in the title of an alert, possible encoding issue?

Tags: encoding, javafx, javafx-8

I trying to write simple method that shows alert dialog and ask user for feedback on my email.

My method:

```
public static void showExceptionDialog(Exception exception) {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
    exception.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    String exceptionText = stringWriter.toString();

    try {
        VBox content = FXMLLoader.load(Dialogs.class.getResource("/org/flycraft/minecraft/droplauncher/exception_dialog_content.fxml"));
        TextArea exceptionTextArea = (TextArea) content.lookup("#exception_text_area");
        exceptionTextArea.setText(exceptionText);
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Ошибка");
        alert.setHeaderText("Что-то пошло не так");

        alert.getDialogPane().setContent(content);

        alert.showAndWait();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But in real dialog i see:
[image]

This is a bug, or something I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, fixed. I use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzgcR.png) plugin for building JavaFX application with gradle. So I just added this line to my build.gradle:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

[image]